# Rails: How to generate and seed db with 100k random users with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to seed my development db with an amount of records that more closely resembles my setup in production. The primary reason for this is driven by optimization. I'd like to test with real data **but** in different amounts, i.e with 25k, 75k, and 125k `Users` etc., all with associations.  The only approach that I can think of is creating different variations of a dump, which would take very long because of how long it takes to delete records! How can one accomplish this task?

Answer (score 6):

one way is [this](https://github.com/stympy/faker)

```
gem 'faker'


offering_type = ["Lunch", "Dinner", "Breakfast", "Tiffin"]


100.times do
    todo = Todoitem.create(
             title:"#{Faker::Company.name} #{Faker::Company.suffix}", 
             offering_type: offering_type.sample,
             website: 'http://www.' + Faker::Internet.domain_name, 
             socialmedia_url:"",
             logo:Faker::Company.logo
           )
    todo.create_associated(associated_hash)
end
```

To dump:

You can write a migration code or rollback

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what's happening in `todo.create_associated(associated_hash)` and where `associated_hash` is coming from?

Comment: To create associated object "visitor" from primary record "todo": `todo.create_visitor(params[:visitor])` - in `params[:visitor]` you can format your own "visitor_hash" as input with keys from `Visitor` model and values using `#Faker` similar to the hash inputs inside `#Todoitem.create(todo_hash)`